# How to insert post data into mysql db with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been troubleshooting this for multiple hours and am not sure why this is not working. I am trying to send a http post with a Qt app and using this as my php script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*.mysql.eu2.*.com:3306","*****","****","****");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$stock= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'stock', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

  $currentid = mysqli_insert_id();

  if (trim($id) == '') {
    exit('id cannot be empty!');
  }
  if (trim($price) == '') {
    exit('price cannot be empty!');
  }
  if (trim($type) == '') {
    exit('type cannot be empty!');
  }
  if (trim($stock ) == '') {
    exit('stock cannot be empty!');
  }

  $result = "insert into ammo (ammoType,storeId,ammoStock,ammoPrice) VALUES ('".$type."','".$id."','".$stock."','".$price."');";

   mysqli_query($result) or die("Could not insert data");



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have been at a point before where I was getting success but then the values were not actually showing up in my db.
Thanks,
-David

Comment: any error its showing or else?

Comment: no way to tell without seeing the HTML form and db schema. check for errors. You're not really doing that. `or die("Could not insert data");` doesn't do much for you.

Comment: you're also not connecting to your query.

Comment: Change `mysqli_query($result) or die("Could not insert data");` to `mysqli_query($con,$result) or die(mysqli_error($con));
`

Comment: @SketchyTurtle use the code that i given and then see what happen?

Comment: thanks all for the quick response.

Comment: @SketchyTurtle  You're very much welcome David, *cheers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you're not connecting to your query.

```
mysqli_query($result)
```

That function requires 2 parameters, and the DB connection first.

```
mysqli_query($con,$result)
```

Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

and you need to check for errors. We don't know what's inside your HTML form and whether you are using a POST method and if your elements bear the right name attributes.

If you get undefined index notices, you'll know what to go for.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

This doesn't help you

```
or die("Could not insert data");
```

this does

```
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

---

You should also be using a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

**N.B.:**

Should MySQL complain about data going in as `Jack's Bar & Grill`, then you will need to escape your data.

- Any which way, you should.

Comment: @SketchyTurtle You're quite welcome, glad I could help. *Cheers*